Period of a real function
I noticed that FunctionPeriod[Mod[t,1],t] returns 1 while FunctionPeriod[Mod[t,1.0],t] returns 0. How can one find the correct period of a function?

No issue on V 14.1  https://i.sstatic.net/nqfRM3PN.png  windows 10

Thank you Nasser. It's good to know that. I was using v 13.2.
